# SharePoint Workflow permissions - where is it inheriting permissions from?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, permissions, inheritance

I used SharePoint Designer 2013 to create an approval workflow which simply modifies the text in the default mails for clarity. It is technically a SharePoint 2010 workflow. I couldn't get the 2013 workflows to work but can't remember the details.

Once the workflow is started, the permissions are set for the appropriate user as it goes through the workflow. However, there are additional permissions that are granted for CERTAIN people with FULL CONTROL, but not all. I can't understand why.

Where are these permissions inherited from? I would like my power users (anyone with FULL CONTROL) to be able to see all tasks no matter where they are in a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In workflow 2010 platform, we can set “Only allow task recipients and process owners to edit workflow tasks” option under settings section when click blue “Approval” in the start approval process action.

If not tick this option, other users with “Contribute” permission level or high level can approve the workflow.

If the users cannot view the tasks, please check if they have permission in the associated task list.

Comment: I am using that option, but I can't find how it is setting those permissions. I have some users set to FULL CONTROL on the site level, and the Task List level, but they are not getting the permissions.